# Fullcalendar events from two different database tables have the same ID

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have two different events an event should appear in red calendar another should be blue. My example below.

```
  editable: true,
  header: {
     left: 'prev,next today',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
  },
  eventSources: [
  {
     url: 'read_simply.php',
     color: 'red',
     textColor: 'white'
  },
  {
     url: 'read_recurring.php',
     color: 'blue',
     textColor: 'white'
  }
],
     theme: true,
     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true,
     droppable: true,
```

Here you can see how the sources are integrated.
Everything works until a little problem. My different events are stored in two different MariaDB tables. Some events have the same "event ID". When I try to move a (red) event to calendar, blue event with the same ID is also moved. How can I correct it???

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the expected behaviour. fullCalendar assumes that events with the same ID are linked and treats them as such.

I would suggest not to use the "id" property for your database IDs (you can just not provide this property, and fullCalendar will create a unique internal ID for itself on each event), and instead set some custom property e.g. `serverID` on your event so that you have a way to link it back to your database, but without causing problems within fullCalendar.